# sparklyr: Permission denied

Tags: sparklyr

I am having problems stablishing connection with spark_connect(master = "local") it has this error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMLG1Xz\file2da459c42c67_spark.log': Permission denied
```

I have changed the environment variables, and also, I have uninstalled and reinstalled sparklyr from GitHub.